# How to get nth row in table with specific class

Tags: jquery

The below is supposed to get the nth row from a table with the .graphedRow class.  It works for the first row, but not the others.

http://jsfiddle.net/hRpAw/

Comment: can you post some code on fiddle?

Comment: now it works [see](http://jsfiddle.net/hRpAw/3/)

Comment: what do you mean? it does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead.

```js
$('#someTable tbody .graphedRow').eq(pointIndex+1).css('background-color', '#FEFF9F');
```

Though it should be noted that `eq()` starts from 0 for index.

---

Did a bit of testing in Firebug.

`:nth-child` is slightly faster than `.eq()` in this case. (Hundredths of a ms faster)

Also, `:nth-child` was working fine, but it bases its index on all children of `#someTable tbody`. It just returns those with the class `.graphedRow`.

So looking at your JSFiddle, you have 6 `<tr>` within `<tbody>` three of which have the class `.graphedRow` (That would be the 1st, 4th and 6th `<tr>`) So `:nth-child(1)`, `:nth-child(4)`, `:nth-child(6)`, would select those.

`:nth-child`'s index still increases due to the other children of `#someTable tbody` (the Other `<tr>` that don't have the class)

Where-as `.eq()`'s index is based on however many instances of `.graphedRow` appear within `#someTable tbody`

Comment: This works! but isn't it slower?  Also, I am curious why :nth-child() doesn't work

Comment: If I recall correctly, nth-child counts all children where-as eq only counts the selector (in this case .graphedRow which is a descendant of tbody which is a descendant of #someTable) - So I believe eq is faster because it only really looks for .graphedRow.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
$('#someTable tbody > tr:nth-child('+index+')').css('background-color', '#FEFF9F')
```

Comment: I don't think you read the question, I need the nth row with a specific class

Comment: there is two different condition, whether u find nth child or find with specific class??

Comment: both.  I need the nth row that has a specific class.  Some rows are in a certain class and some are not.. I need the nth row that is in that class